# Where can I find the turn radius on the ground for the Piper Seminole?

Tags: poh

I meant to be doing a quiz for a class and one of the questions is asking for the turn radius of the Piper Seminole. However I cant find it anywhere in the POH.

Do you know where I can look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

33.0 ft From pivot point to wingtip, it is in the POH page 1-2

Comment: Welcome to Av.SE